# VB.Net and VS 2010 Append a variable to an URL

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm a newbie writing my first app.  I need help with the following: I need to retrieve the logged in user which = GID, I then need to append it to a URL which will start our Help Desk chat client.  I can retrieve the GID easy enough but can't figure out how to append it and pass it with the URL.  I found a post which instructed to declare the url as a string also and concatenate it.  The UserName would follow the ":" at the end of the Url.

```
Private Sub GID()
        Dim GID As String
        GID = System.Environment.UserName

        '  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.myurl.com/eschat/arhome.html?login=m:uid~uid:")
```

We use javascript to do this from the HelpDesk site, but I need to adapt it to work from my app. Any help would be appreciated and I hope my question makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate strings in VB.NET using '&' like this:

```
Dim GID as String
GID =  System.Environment.UserName
Dim URL as String
URL = "http://www.myurl.com/eschat/arhome.html?login=m:uid~uid:"

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(URL & GID)
```

You can also insert the variable into the string like this

```
URL = String.Format("http://www.myurl.com/eschat/arhome.html?login=m:uid~uid:{0}", GID)
```

and the GID will be placed wherever the "{0}" is, this can also be used for multiple parameters, you just increment the number inside the curly braces e.g. "{1}", "{2}".

MSDN article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx#Y200).